# Throttling a thread with a life span timer

Tags: multithreading, throttling

I am setting up a job queue service and need to throttle threads and also limit the life of the job running in the thread, not the thread life itself.  Please do not get on a soap box on how bad Thread.Abort() is. I have thoroughly considered the consequences of two evils and in my case, this is the better choice. Abort() may never actually get called, but if it every does, it will be needed.
I can get throttling and thread life time to work with the following code but the timer starts even then the job is waiting to start because of the throttle threshold has been exceeded. Is there a way I can get the timer to start ONLY when the job starts, not the thread only?

Thank you

Earl

```
            var workerThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                concurrencySemaphore.Wait();
                try
                {

                    consumerHelper.Execute(job, JobMessage, communicate);;
                }
                finally
                {

                    concurrencySemaphore.Release();
                }

            });

            var timeoutTimer = new System.Threading.Timer((s) =>
            {
                workerThread.Abort();
            }, null, jobTimeSpan, TimeSpan.FromHours(12));

            workerThread.Start();
```

What I need is the timer to start when the job actually starts running, not just when thread starts running.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. I created a custom event handler and passed it the thread just before starting the job. In the event handler I started the timer. works like a charm.